# Makefile with user input validation

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I've make file with target that needs some variable (token) as **pre-requisite**

e.g.

```
token = 

deploy:
   http://api.run.cf.com $(token)
```

I need that the user enter the token (to the file) before he run the `make deploy`

If not provide some error, how can I do it ?

I've tried to add

`ifndef token
    @echo Warning: token isn\'t defined\; abort`

However  not sure how to integrate it to the `  deploy target.

Comment: Is it possible to read the token from a file? This has the benefit to be able to run without interaction should you ever want to move the process to a build server. make likes files. make hates console. Really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User can add variables on the fly when running `make`

Example:

```
$ VAR1=44 OPTIONFORMKE=true make
```

This will set:

```
VAR1=44
&
OPTIONFORMAKE=true
```

as if they were provided as input parameters.

and in `Makefile` you can check

```
if [ "$OPTIONFORMAKE" == "true" ];then echo doing something here; fi
```

same for VAR1 or any other on-the-fly variable you want to pass

Comment: Thanks, not sure that I got the complete flow,  how the if statement related to the target which i need to run , as I dont want to allow to run it if token is missing...

Comment: with the if statement you can check if the required token/variable is missing, and if it is echo a warning and `exit 1`